# Manipulating <head> </head> section in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I need help with updating the  section in Joomla interface. I am trying to add additional elements and snippets of JQuery into the `<head></head>`. Where do i access this within Joomla?

on another note - i can't directly the source or find a manipulate HTML button/source button. Is this something i need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add scripts & CSS to the head , I think what you're asking is described at [Adding JavaScript and CSS to the page](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page), specifically in the section titled [Inserting inline scripts from within a PHP file](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page#Inserting_inline_scripts_from_within_a_PHP_file).

To your secondary question, I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: I found it within the Template section... Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I was about to mention templates just as your comment came through, lol.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what GDP said, depending on your specific needs you may want to use one of the multiple available 3rd party plugins instead. You an find a handful of them at the JED:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/head-code